# Process wiki dumps using gwtwiki "Usage: Parser <XML-FILE>" Error

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, wikimedia-dumps, bliki

I am trying to process a wikimedia dump file (eg: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20150304/enwiki-20150304-pages-meta-history9.xml-p000897146p000925000.bz2) using gwtwiki and java. I am pretty new to java (I could understand and write simple java scripts) and I'm using eclipse. I have imported the gwtwiki project and tried to run the DumpExample.java and I got the `Usage: Parser <XML-FILE>` response error.

I don't know where to define the path of the .bz2 dump file and tried to at least edit the Usage: `Parser <XML-FILE>` error response to something else but I got the same result even when trying to run it step by step or adding a few more lines of code like `System.out.println("test");`

Documentation offers no explanation of how exactly this should be done as I imagine that for someone that knows java well this should be pretty self explanatory.

Now, i don't need a step by step tutorial on how can I achieve this but I would like a starting point or a few clues and I will do my learning on my own. After searching for days I see that I don't even know where to start. I also know you could say something like:

> Learn more Java!

but I always learn better by actually engaging in a project like this.

The **DumpExample.java**:

```
package info.bliki.wiki.dump;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
 * Demo application which reads a compressed or uncompressed Wikipedia XML dump
 * file (depending on the given file extension <i>.gz</i>, <i>.bz2</i> or
 * <i>.xml</i>) and prints the title and wiki text.
 * 
 */
public class DumpExample {
    /**
     * Print title an content of all the wiki pages in the dump.
     * 
     */
    static class DemoArticleFilter implements IArticleFilter {

        public void process(WikiArticle page, Siteinfo siteinfo) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(page.getId());
            System.out.println(page.getRevisionId());
            System.out.println(page.getTitle());
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(page.getText());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print all titles of the wiki pages which have &quot;Real&quot; content
     * (i.e. the title has no namespace prefix) (key == 0).
     */
    static class DemoMainArticleFilter implements IArticleFilter {

        public void process(WikiArticle page, Siteinfo siteinfo) throws SAXException {
            if (page.isMain()) {
                System.out.println(page.getTitle());
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Print all titles of the wiki pages which are templates (key == 10).
     */
    static class DemoTemplateArticleFilter implements IArticleFilter {

        public void process(WikiArticle page, Siteinfo siteinfo) throws SAXException {
            if (page.isTemplate()) {
                System.out.println(page.getTitle());
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Print all titles of the wiki pages which are categories (key == 14).
     */
    static class DemoCategoryArticleFilter implements IArticleFilter {

        public void process(WikiArticle page, Siteinfo siteinfo) throws SAXException {
            if (page.isCategory()) {
                System.out.println(page.getTitle());
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 1) {
            System.out.println("test");
            System.out.println("test");
            System.out.println("test");
            System.out.println("test");
            System.err.println("Usagessss: Parser <XML-FILEZZZZZZ>");
            System.out.println("test2");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        // String bz2Filename =
        // "c:\\temp\\dewikiversity-20100401-pages-articles.xml.bz2";
        String bz2Filename = args[0];
        try {
            IArticleFilter handler = new DemoArticleFilter();
            WikiXMLParser wxp = new WikiXMLParser(bz2Filename, handler);
            wxp.parse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I just wanna say: Good on you for getting started early with documenting yourself! It's a fantastic habit to get into. You may have horrible design patterns (I can't tell) but documentation can make your code at least understandable 90% of the time. It's still better to write good code, of course, but in a pinch you can fall back on docs while you refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, maybe it will help you or if you've moved on, mayby it will help the next person stumbling onto this post, I'm using this implementation:

```
    File f = new File("c:/path/to/svwiki-20151102-pages-meta-current.xml");
    WikiXMLParser wxp;
    try {
        wxp = new WikiXMLParser(f, handler);
        wxp.parse();
    } catch (IOException e) {   
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```